# How to echo a converted time format from mysql datetime column

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

I'm trying to convert datetimte to something shorter, but i get some error as below.

> **Warning: `date_format()` expects parameter 1 to be DateTime, string given in ...**

**CODE**

```
$datetime = '2012-03-24 17:45:12';
$time = date_format($datetime, 'g:i A');
echo $time;
```

What i'm i doing wring?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this with [DateTime](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php)

```
$date = new DateTime("2012-03-24 17:45:12");
echo $date->format("g:i A");
```

Answer (score 0):

`date_format` formats a date object. You have a strong.

Try `date("g:I A", strtotime($datetime))`

Answer (score 0):

this will also work for you-

```
$datetime = date_create('2012-03-24 17:45:12');
$time = date_format($datetime, 'g:i A');
echo $time;
```